# d3 bar chart is upside down

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple bar chart drawn in d3, with vertical bars: http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/LjxaV/2/

However, it's drawing the bars down, with the baseline at the top of the chart.

I've read that to invert this, drawing up from the bottom, I should change the `range()` on the y-axis. So, change this:

```
    .range([0, chart.style('height')]);
```

to this:

```
    .range([chart.style('height'), 0]);
```

However, that looks like it's drawing the inverse of the chart - drawing in the space *above* each of the bars, and leaving the bars themselves (drawn from the bottom) transparent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per the d3 basic bar chart : 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

You are correct in inverting the range.

Additionally, your rectangles should be added like this:

```
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.percent); } )
    .attr('height', function(d,i){ return height - y(d.percent); });
```

Comment: Great, thanks cmonkey. I hadn't seen that bar chart example either, so that's useful.

Answer (score 2):

The x and y coordinates for `svg` start in the top left. You want the y to start on the bottom. The code below assumes you're appending to some function along the lines of:

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
```

To make the bar plot act as you desire, set the y attribute to begin at distance `data[i]` above the axis:

```
.attr('y', function(d) { return height - d; })
```

Then, you must make the distance extend the remaining `data[i]` to the axis.

```
.attr('height', function(d) { return d; })
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the y attribute seems to work:

```
.attr('y', function(d){ return (height - parseInt(y(d.percent))); })
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LjxaV/4/)

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I think that just moves the bars done, rather than inverting the chart, which may cause problems with displaying y-axis marks later on.