# d3 js - how to invert d3.extent

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have drawn my axes in d3 using the d3.extent method to determine the max and min values for the axis.

However, by default, d3 draws the y axis upside down ([d3 bar chart is upside down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011256/d3-bar-chart-is-upside-down)) and I need to invert it.

How to I tell the extent method to invert the results?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far, ideally with some fiddle or similar

Comment: I've managed to find a way to make it work, but was wondering if there was a single function to do it!

Comment: Ok, now I understand... a one-liner: `d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(data.History, function (d) { return d.ArrivalTime; }).reverse())`...

Comment: reverse! Makes perfect sense. Do you want to drop that into an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [d3.extent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent) function in combination with [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
var yScale = d3.time.scale()
               .domain(d3.extent(data.History, function (d) { return d.ArrivalTime; }).reverse())
               .range([margin.top, chartHeight - margin.top * 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it manually using the following code. I can't find a neater way than this:

```
 var yMax = d3.max(data.History, function (d) { return d.ArrivalTime });
 var yMin = d3.min(data.History, function (d) { return d.ArrivalTime });

var yScale = d3.time.scale()
                .domain([yMax, yMin])
                .range([margin.top, chartHeight - margin.top * 2]);
```