# D3 bar chart same values on chart but data different

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <title>D3 Bar chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Bar Chart</h1>

    <script>
        //D3 Code
    var w = 500;
    var h = 100;

    var dataset = [14, 5, 26, 23, 9];
    var barPadding = 45;
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length - barPadding);
        })
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 100);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment when I run my code I get a bar chart but its the same for each bar so it is just a chart with the same value but my dataset in my code are different values. How do I change my code so I can get a proper bar chart to produce?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `height`. You can pass a function like

```
.attr("height", dataValue => dataValue);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <title>D3 Bar chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Bar Chart</h1>

    <script>
        //D3 Code
    var w = 500;
    var h = 100;

    var dataset = [14, 5, 26, 23, 9];
    var barPadding = 45;
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length - barPadding);
        })
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", dataValue => dataValue);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ah thank you @Eric Na. One more question how would I get the bar chart to flip so it is the correct way. I was able to lower everything by changing .attr("y",0) to .attr("y",50) but I cant figure out how to flip it?

Comment: You should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011256/d3-bar-chart-is-upside-down. I think there are a few things missing from your code.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't do anything, thanks for the help though